# Continuous group representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, representation-theory

Suppose you have a topological
group $G$ 
, a normed $k$-
vector space $V$ and a group homomorphism $\rho:G\longrightarrow GL(V)$. How do you define the topology on $GL(V)$ to make this
map continuous?

Many thanks

Comment: You could equip $\operatorname{GL}(V)$ with the indiscrete topology, which makes every map into it continuous, but somehow I doubt this is what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle this is standard: what we really want is that $G\times V\rightarrow V$ by $g\times v\rightarrow \rho(g)(v)$ is (jointly) continuous. This correctly suggests taking the "strong operator topology" on (continuous) operators $V\rightarrow V$, namely, the seminorms $p_v(T)=|Tv|$ for $v\in V$, Banach, say.

With the uniform operator norm topology on endomorphisms of $V$, rarely will $G\rightarrow GL(V)$ be continuous. This is not a pathology, but a natural occurrence: already with $G$ being the circle acting on $V=L^2(G)$, the map $G\rightarrow GL(V)$ is not continuous when $GL(V)$ is given the uniform norm operator topology.

Edit: the topology is given by the collection of *all* such seminorms. The resulting topology on continuous operators is not Banach, etc. That is, there's no "open ball of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $T$". A basis for the open nbds of given $T$ are indexed by finite lists of vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_n$, small $\epsilon>0$, and requiring $|(T-S)v_i|<\epsilon$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$.

Comment: Your seminorm depends on the vector $v\in V$, I can't see how this can give a topology on $GL(V)$. So what is an open ball centered at $T$?

Comment: So an automorphism $S$ lies in an open nbd of $T$ if it satisfies the finitely many inequalities above? And are you saying the map $(g,T)\rightarrow \rho(g)(T)$ is then continuous?

Comment: Yes to the first question, but I'd say $(g,v)\rightarrow \rho(g)(v)$ is continuous. Maybe you didn't write what you meant.

Comment: You're right, what I meant was with $v$. Can you tell me where I can find a proof that this map is continuous?

Comment: This appears in almost every book about representation theory. For example, it's on page 4 of my notes about such stuff: http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/v/unitary_of_top.pdf

Comment: Many thanks for the reference

Answer (score 1):

If $V$ is a normed real (or complex) vector space, then prove that $GL(V)$ is a normed real (or complex) vector space with the following norm:

$\left\|T\right\|=\sup_{\left\|v\right\|=1}\left\|Tv\right\|$

for $T\in GL(V)$. (We use the same notation, $\left\|\cdot\right\|$, for both the norm on $V$ and in the definition of the norm on $GL(V)$ using the norm on $V$; I hope this doesn't cause confusion.)

I hope this helps!

**Edit**: It appears that I didn't read your question as carefully as I should have and that you are looking for a topology on $GL(V)$ such that a given group homomorphism $\rho:G\to GL(V)$ is continuous. The norm on $GL(V)$ that I defined above is the natural norm induced by the given norm on $V$.

I'm keeping this answer up anyway in case it's useful.

Comment: If $V$ is infinite-dimensional, there may be unbounded operators in $GL(V)$ for which this norm is undefined.

Comment: @Brad +1 Thanks Brad! You're certainly right. I was thinking about finite-dimensional vector spaces in my answer but as you say my answer isn't applicable to infinite-dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: Thanks for your answers- I was wondering if there is a natural definition for 'open' sets or maybe for a basis of open sets in $GL(V)$.

Comment: Dear @MarkRodriguez, if $V$ is a finite dimensional complex or real vector space ($V \cong \Bbb{R}^n$ or $\Bbb{C}^n$ for some $n$), then $\text{GL}(V)$ can be identified with an open subset of $\Bbb{R}^{n^2}$ or $\Bbb{C}^{n^2}$. Any open subset of a manifold inherits  a manifold structure from the parent manifold, simply by restriction of open sets and charts.

Comment: BTW, I will vote up the answers when I get enough reputation points.